# How to properly implement Ajax with DataTables using Django?

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, django, datatables

I have a database that I would like to manifest as a datatable within my Django app. However, I'm having some trouble trying to get the required model data parsed to my Ajax-enabled template.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    someAttr = models.CharField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.someAttr
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core import serializers
from .models import MyModel

def myModel_asJson(request):
    object_list = MyModel.objects.all()
    json = serializers.serialize('json', object_list)
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'json': json})
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('myapp.views',
                    url(regex=r'^$',
                    view='myModel_asJson',
                    name='my_ajax_url'),
)
```

**template.html**

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="example">
     <thead>
         <tr><th>My Attr Heading</th></tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody></tbody>
</table>


<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#example').dataTable( {
             "processing": true,
             "ajax": {
                 "processing": true,
                 "url": "{% url 'my_ajax_url' %}",
                 "dataSrc": ""
             },

             "columns": [
                     { "data": "fields.someAttr" },
                     { "data": "pk" }
                 ]
         } );
     } );
 </script>
```

When I open the webpage, I am greeted with an error, stating that my json is not valid. I have verified that the json is in fact valid, but the data is still not showing on my datatable.

I've no idea how to get around this error. Any help in the matter would be greatly appreciated, I would really like to implement ajax and datatables within my django app to display my model data.